# Toggle only One <ul> from multiple instances With Same Class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a responsive multilevel drop down navigation Bar. I have multiple  with same class name. I want to toggle only one but jquery effect all the . There is a button with class "toggle-dropdown" for every

which has another level of navigation.

My Codes are:

HTML

```
<h2>Vertical Navigation Bar</h2>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news" class="has-children">News</a>
  <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">expand child menu</button>
    <ul class="sub-menu">

        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="has-children">About</a>
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">expand child menu</button>
            <ul class="sub-menu">

                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul 
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li 
{
    border-top: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    position: relative;
}

ul a 
{
    margin-right: 56px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.3125;
    outline-offset: -1px;
    padding: 0.84375em 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-toggle 
{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    content: "";
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    top: 0;
    width: 48px;
}


.sub-menu
{
    display:block;
    padding-left:20px;
}


.dropdown-toggle 
{ 

    right:0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    top: 0;
    width: 48px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function()
    {
        $(".sub-menu").toggle(1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.sibilings()` or `.next()` methods:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".sub-menu").toggle(1000);
    // or
    // $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").toggle(1000);
});
```

As class name selectors always returns a collection of all elements. So, in your case clicking on one `button` expands all the `.sub-menu` list.

Now you have to filter them to get the siblings elements only with `.siblings()` or `.next()` methods.

Comment: I was also trying with sibling(), next(), parent(), children() but in a wrong way so i was not getting correct output. Thanks again,

Answer (score 2):

You can use .next() methods. It is return immediately following sibling of "dropdown-toggle" class. By mentioning specific class. It return specific div of specific class. You can know more about .next() methods in the below url -->
[jquery next](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

Copy the below javascript code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function()
    {
         $(this).next(".sub-menu").toggle(1000);
    });
});
</script>
```